# How to create new dataframe out of total values based on specific column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
A  B  C
X  U  500
X  S  300
X  T  200
Y  F  20
Y  G  980
Z  L  400
```

I would like to use specific values in column A so {X, Y, Y} and based on those values, I'd like to take the row C total sum and output it in a new dataframe. My new dataframe should like something like this

```
A  B
X  1000
Y  1000
Z  400
```

It is essentially grouping the values by name in column A, taking the total sum of C from each of those values in A, and creating a new dataframe with the name specified in column A with the totals from column C.

I need it to pick up on these values on its own, because imagine my dataframe has 200 rows and 80 different values in column A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B'].sum()
```

Or:

```
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: can i email you some questions - i noticed your email on your profile?

Comment: Yes, sure. No problem.